# Wordpress Filter get_projects_category();

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to amend the `<?php get_projects_category(); ?>` to only get projects from specific categories? The previous code is populating a menu with category links, and I only want certain projects to be listed in the menu.

Full Code for custom function below:

```
function get_projects_category() {
        global $project_page_url;
        if(get_option('arch_hide_project_drop')!="true") {
            ?>
                <div class="cat-toogles">
                    <a href="#" class="pfilter">
                        <?php if(get_option('arch_project_cfilter')!="") { echo get_option('arch_project_cfilter'); } else { _e( 'Filter Works', ENGINE_THEME_NAME ); } ?> <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    </a>    
                    <ul class="cat-list">                       
                        <li <?php if(is_page_template('template-projects.php')) { echo "class='current-cat'";  } ?>>
                            <a href="<?php echo $project_page_url; ?>">
                                <?php if(get_option('arch_pcategory_label')!="") { echo get_option('arch_pcategory_label'); } else { _e( 'View all', ENGINE_THEME_NAME ); } ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                            $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'project_categories', 'style' => 'list', 'title_li' => '', 'hierarchical' => false, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
                            wp_list_categories ( $args );                           
                        ?>  
                    </ul>
                </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a custom function, not built into WordPress itself. You should post the code for that function. Or have a look at it yourself: does it have a call to filter the results or query?

Comment: @MSTannu Alright, i've posted the code for the function. Good call.

Comment: Look at the arguments in `wp_list_categories` and adjust accordingly

Comment: @PieterGoosen The argument for wp_list_category includes 'project_categories' within the array. I'm guessing now my question is how do I amend or filter this part of the array so only certain project categories are called, not all. Any thoughts?

Comment: What I meant is, check `wp-list_categories` in the codex. Your function don't have filters, so you'll need to modify the function it self or create a new one. This should be your starting point. I really don't have time to code now, unfortunately it is late and I'm off to be bed now. Let me know if you don't succeed on this, then I'll see what I can do tommorrow.

Comment: The function `wp_list_categories` can be given additional parameters like `include` or `exclude`, a comma separated string of ids in each case. Check the documentation for full details: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories